# Puppeteer click on button not executed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm trying to execute the below code in order to click on button:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('button1 bg-white[type=submit]').click();
});
```

This is my HTML code (in my React app render):

```
<Button size="mini" className= "button1 bg-white" onClick={() => {
                            this.onChangeTimeFilter('7d')
                        }} primary={this.state.timeFilter === '7d'} content="7d"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector needs to be '.button1.bg-white'

Note:

1. period before each class name
2. No space between the "button1" and "bg-white" class names
3. I removed [type=submit] because there's nothing in your JSX code to indicate you have a submit button there

Comment: Thanks! I've change the selector but still getting error.`(node:24336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null`
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:52

Comment: It works like that thank you! `await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelector('.button1').click();
    });`

Comment: A simpler way of doing this with puppeteer would be:

[`await page.click('.button1')`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options)

Comment: another question regarding - if I would like to change dropdown option what is the correct way to do it ?       var objSelect = document.querySelector(".div.ui.active.visible.selection.dropdown.gray-border");
        //Set selected
        setSelectedValue(objSelect, "by Room");
        function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
            for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
                if (selectObj.text === valueToSet) {
                    selectObj.selected = true;
                    return;
               }
            }
        }